# Raspbian GUI Headless

Tags: raspbian, display, headless, gui

I'm planning to run Raspbian on a Model B v1 (256MB) Pi, and I'd rather not have the memory overhead of a GUI running in the background.

I know that there are a few Raspbian Server respins available but I'd prefer to use vanilla Raspbian for simplicity. Note that I'm not necessarily concerned about disk/SD space, but more about available RAM.

My question is: **does Raspbian auto-start X by default, or does it only start a DE if a display is detected?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in the comment, yes there is also a way. After you flash the image onto the SD card, locate the config.txt file. Open it in a text editor, I suggest Notepad++.
Find and change "start_x=" to either one (for GUI) or zero (for terminal). Save and reboot!
This should work!

Answer (score 4):

If your Pi is set up to boot to the desktop, it will start X even if no display is connected.

You can run this command to run the config utility:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and go into the option for boot settings and select 'Boot to CLI'

Comment: Thanks - is there any way to set this on a freshly-flashed SD card by modifying the files on the SD before first boot?